# Xcode - build phase or script for copying only modified files to App Bundle

Tags: xcode, file, build-process, copy

Mac OS X 10.5 compatibility required. Xcode 3.2.5.

My app looks in the bundle's Resources folder, for a "data" folder.

"data" contains a hierarchy of subfolders and data. The contents are constantly being modified.

I don't need to navigate or modify this data within Xcode.

**Q.** When building, how can I copy "data" (say, from the Xcode project's folder) to the Resources folder, but only copying those files within "data" that have been modified since the last build?

(Simply copying all files every time I build is not feasible; the file sizes are too large, slowing build times.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem to use `rsync` in a shell script build phase.  Something like this:

```
rsync -a "${SRCROOT}/data" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
```

That does a bit more than date comparison but it should still be quite a bit faster than what you're doing now.

The above doesn't delete any files you removed from the source directory; to do so, you can add `--delete` but I'd only suggest doing that after you're sure it's working properly.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas. I can't test this just now as I had to go with another approach, but I'll try it for the next project.

Comment: Sure, was just looking at your old questions and surprised nobody got to this one!

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. This works a treat with the --delete option. Cheers.