# XCode build phase with rsync not deleting files from bundle

Tags: xcode, build-process, build-automation, rsync, resourcebundle

I have two resource folders added as folder references to my XCode project. Following the advice on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252239/xcode-build-phase-or-script-for-copying-only-modified-files-to-app-bundle) I created a new build phase that copies those folders using the rsync command, so that changes to files inside this folder would appear when the app is run without needing to clean the project. I then placed the build phase right afer "Copy Bundle Resources" and removed my two folders from that. Here are the commands for the build phase:

```
rsync -a --delete --exclude=.svn "${SRCROOT}/Resources/Episode1" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
rsync -a --delete --exclude=.svn "${SRCROOT}/Resources/Common" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
```

It seems to work fine, however files deleted are still inside my app bundle. I noticed that if I go to the folder represented by "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" the files I deleted are not there as expected, but if I inspect my app bundle inside the simulator the files are there still. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to do a clean build and or delete the app from your simulator/ios device every now and then when using rsync like this.

Check out the rsync man page though:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html

I use the following command in my projects:

```
rsync -avzq --exclude='.DS_Store' --exclude='.*' "${SRCROOT}/bin/data/" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
```

I don't use the --delete as this removes the deployment build / Xcode provisions deployed in the main app directory in my case